# MBProgressHUD tap to cancel, longer text?

Tags: iphone, touch, mbprogresshud

I'd like to use MBProgressHUD (or similar look) as alternative to default UIAlertView.

I need a canceling capability on this view.
I tried adding the following method to MBProgressHUD class but it didn't get called when touched.

Any idea?

> (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet*) touches withEvent: (UIEvent*)event

I can't use gesture recognizer since my lowest target version is 3.1.2.

Also, it seems complex to enlarge label size for MBProgressHUD's text.
Are there altanatives than fixing MBProgessHUD for the purpose?

Comment: `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self hideUsingAnimation:YES];
}` works quite well for me.

Comment: Nekto: mine doesn't work..MBProgressHUD.m says it's version is 0.4 what are you using?

Comment: Nekto: nvm, i put the code inside @implementation MBRoundProgressView
 not in MBProgressHUD.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had quick look at MBProgressHUD and would use that. First, change the size of the HUD by modifying layoutSubviews in MBProgressHUD.h. I would then create a new button class (UIButton subclass) and add this as a subview of the HUD.

Answer (score 2):

This is a super old thread, but it would be way easier just to set hud's UserInteractionEnabled:YES and add a tapGestureRecognizer to it.

Cheers.